# PHP Infinite arguments after important ones

Tags: php

Alright so Ive got a little problem, I am basically trying to make a system where I could just do CreateUser("Name", "password", "Not bad", "Too risky");
Just as an example. Basically 2 important arguments and the rest I Want to get dynamically.

```
function createUser($username, $password, $comments) {
            if($comments >= 1) {
                echo $comments[0];
            }
        }
```

Comment: `function createUser($username, $password, ...$comments) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the $comments variable an array.

```
function createUser($username, $password, $comments=array()) {
    if($comments >= 1) {
            echo $comments[0];
        }
    }
createUser("test","testpw",array("Not bad","Too risky"));
```

Comment: Yes but doing $comments[0] will display only the first letter of $comments for some reason

Comment: That is because it is the first item in the array.  You will need to add some logic to the function to decide what comment to return.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasnt using array inside the function when I was using the function that was the problem